# Función Xquery que recibe un parámetro y devuelve otro de un nodo diferente (BaseX)

Tags: xml, xquery

Al realizar la función me encuentro con el error "context is undeclared", necesito iterar sobre el nodo para sacar el nombre, pasarlo como parametro y devolver el escudo del qeuipo que se encuentra en otro nodo.

Este es mi código:

```
declare function local:escudo($name as xs:string) as xs:string {
  let $let :=//eventos/evento/escudoLocal[equipolocal = $name]/text()
  return $let
}; 
for $x in //grupos/grupo/clasificacion/team
return
<escudo>{local:escudo ($x/name/text())}</escudo>
```

También lo he intentado de esta forma:

```
declare function local:escudo($name as xs:string) as xs:string {
  if ($name = //evento/equipolocal/text()) then
  let $let :=//escudoLocal/text()
  return $let
}; 
for $x in //team
return
<escudo>{local:escudo($x/name/text())}</escudo>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No tienes que especificar obligatoriamente que tipo de parámetro o función es (quita el xs:string), aunque sea una buena practica, no siempre va a ser útil.
- Cuando estas trabajando con una función, si quieres usar un elemento de un xml, tienes que hacer referencia al documento si o sí, por lo que veo, en tu caso sería "futbol.xml".
- Lo mejor que puedes hacer es asignar el valor primero, usas una clausula where para definir cuando quieres que se asigne y cuando no, no uses un if de primeras, luego en el return haces un if y else (no puedes concaternarlos, ya lo he intentado)

```
declare function local:obtain_escudo($nombre_equipo){
  for $x in doc("futbol.xml")//evento
  where $x/equipolocal/text() = $nombre_equipo or $x/equipovisitante/text() = $nombre_equipo
  return
  if($x/equipolocal/text() = $nombre_equipo) then $x/escudoLocal/text() else($x/escudoVisitante/text())
};
```